# How to deploy my django app to a URL?

Tags: django, web-deployment, windows-server-2012, setup-deployment, windows-server

I've developed an application using Django.

Recently I bought a link from `www.godaddy.com`. I already have a server and I will install windows server or windows 7.

Can anyone give me step-by-step instructions of how to deploy my django app to the link I have?

I developed my django app on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: There is *already* step by step instructions on deployment in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please not use Windows. Install CentoOS, point your domain to server ip, ssh via putty, then install apache. Then git pull from your repository with code or just use ftp, then write a config for apache and visit you domain name.

Comment: Thank you! Do you propose any version of CentoOS, like Server or just the latest version?

Comment: Thank you once again! I'll try it as soon as possible and I'll give you a feedback.